# how to set windows service username and password through commandline

Tags: windows, service, command-line

Using **sc** command we can query, start , stop windows services.
For ex:

```
sc query "windows service name"
```

The **sc config** command changes the configuration of the service, but I don't know how to use it.

Could someone tell me how we can set the username and password for any windows service?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

This works:

```
sc.exe config "[servicename]" obj= "[.\username]" password= "[password]"
```

Where each of the [bracketed] items are replaced with the true arguments. (Keep the quotes, but don't keep the brackets.)

Just keep in mind that:

- The spacing in the above example matters.  `obj= "foo"` is correct; `obj="foo"` is not.
- '.' is an alias to the local machine, you can specify a domain there (or your local computer name) if you wish.
- Passwords aren't validated until the service is started
- Quote your parameters, as above.  You can sometimes get by without quotes, but good luck.

Comment: Andrew , it worked with minor changes. obj= "domain\username" obj= "LocalSystem" we have to have space inbetween obj= and username. userid's are validated that is good. we have to have blank space in between password= and actual password. password are not validated, that is bit of pain. to set back the service again to LocalSystem, which do have passsword, we have give some dummy password to make it work. like sc config "servicename" obj= "LocalSystem" password= "notused"

Comment: When I tried running this command in PowerShell, I got errors like: "Set-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'obj='." I worked around it by using CMD: `cmd.exe -e "sc config Service obj= user password= pass"`

Comment: This does not work either. The SC config *service* obj= "*service name*" password= "*password*" does not correctly set the password -- thus, the service cannot be started.

Comment: @Jeremy In powershell, "sc" is an alias to Set-Content. Use `& sc.exe` instead and there won't be a conflict.

Comment: If the service has "interact with desktop" set already, you'll get an error code 87. To get around this: `sc.exe config "ServiceName" obj= "USER@DOMAIN" password= "MyPassword" TYPE= own` (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/264663)

Comment: I always get logon failure when setting password through cmd. When I manually go have add the same password it works. No special characters in my password and I'm using double quotes as well

Comment: @OmairNabiel as Rich K says in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408973/using-sc-exe-to-set-service-credentials-password-fails "When you configure a service to run under a specific account via the normal route from the service properties windows automatically grants the account the log in as service right. When you use sc.exe you also have to grant the user the log on as service right."

Answer (score 9):

In PowerShell, the "sc" command is an alias for the Set-Content cmdlet. You can workaround this using the following syntax:

```
sc.exe config Service obj= user password= pass
```

Specyfying the .exe extension, PowerShell bypasses the alias lookup.

HTH

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I wonder if this method support other characters different than alphanumeric.

Comment: Can also just whack a "cmd /c" in front of the sc command line which makes PowerShell run it in CMD