# Powershell script to change service account

Tags: windows, powershell

Does anyone have a Powershell script to change the credentials used by a Windows service?

Comment: Can you remove the bonus question text? I notice you posted that separately. Let's not confuse people and have the answers go to the wrong place.

Comment: [Using `sc.exe`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/308298/1394393) is also an option.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Bit easier - use WMI.

```
$service = gwmi win32_service -computer [computername] -filter "name='whatever'"
$service.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,"P@ssw0rd")
```

Change the service name appropriately in the filter; set the remote computer name appropriately.

Comment: Just a note on this answer. If you want to update the user account, you need to be update the value preceding password. i.e. $service.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,".\MyAccount","P@ssw0rd"). It seems you always need to prefix the account name with the domain name or ".\" otherwise it won't work. For more information regarding the other parameters please see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384901(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Also, take a look at my answer below before using this.  Service account changes require a service reset to take effect and sample code is included.

Comment: Note that if you are specifying an account other than Local System as per @Rohland's comment above, you must also specify $false for parameter 6 ("DesktopInteract").  Only the Local System account can be granted permissions to interact with the desktop.

Comment: my password has a '$' in it, how do I escape that?

Comment: You should be able to use a hard (single) quote instead.

Comment: I had a lot of trouble with this approach... lots of assorted failures.  I ended up finding that invoking sc was a lot more reliable: `& sc.exe config "$servicename" obj= "[$domain\$username]" password= "[$password]"`  -- reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308298/

Comment: Instead of filtering on name, you can filter on DisplayName, might alleviate issues where there is a '$' in the name.

Comment: For anyone interested in the signature of that change() method of the Win32_Service class look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384901(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If I need access to ComputerName using a username and password, not the same that windows service credential ?

Comment: not working. nor the sc in Windows 2019 data center. If it is manually changed to the user and then run, it works (but that is not what I wanted)

Answer (score 41):

I wrote a function for PowerShell that changes the username, password, and restarts a service on a remote computer (you can use localhost if you want to change the local server).  I've used this for monthly service account password resets on hundreds of servers.

You can find a copy of the original at http://www.send4help.net/change-remote-windows-service-credentials-password-powershel-495

It also waits until the service is fully stopped to try to start it again, unlike one of the other answers.

```
Function Set-ServiceAcctCreds([string]$strCompName,[string]$strServiceName,[string]$newAcct,[string]$newPass){
  $filter = 'Name=' + "'" + $strServiceName + "'" + ''
  $service = Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $strCompName -namespace "root\cimv2" -class Win32_Service -Filter $filter
  $service.Change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$newAcct,$newPass)
  $service.StopService()
  while ($service.Started){
    sleep 2
    $service = Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $strCompName -namespace "root\cimv2" -class Win32_Service -Filter $filter
  }
  $service.StartService()
}
```

Comment: Great +1. You should edit and include usage line. Usage: Set-ServiceAcctCreds -strCompName "Computer1" -strServiceName "Service" -newAcct "DOM\ServiceUser" -newPass 'newSecureWord'

Answer (score 23):

The PowerShell 6 version of [`Set-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-service?view=powershell-6#notes) now has the `-Credential` parameter.

Here is an example:

```
$creds = Get-Credential
Set-Service -DisplayName "Remote Registry" -Credential $creds
```

At this point, it is only available via download via [GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell#get-powershell).

Enjoy!

Comment: I think `-Credentials` should actually be `-Credential`

Answer (score 16):

I created a text file "changeserviceaccount.ps1" containing the following script:

```
$account="domain\user"
$password="passsword"
$service="name='servicename'"

$svc=gwmi win32_service -filter $service
$svc.StopService()
$svc.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$account,$password,$null,$null,$null)
$svc.StartService()
```

I used this as part of by post-build command line during the development of a windows service:

Visual Studio: Project properties\Build Events

Pre-build event command line:

```
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\installutil.exe" myservice.exe /u
```

Post-build event command line:

```
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\installutil.exe" myservice.exe
powershell -command - < c:\psscripts\changeserviceaccount.ps1
```

Answer (score 8):

A slight variation on the other scripts here, is below. This one will set credentials for any/all services running under a given login account. It will only attempt to restart the service if it was already running, so that we don't accidentally start a service that was stopped for a reason. The script has to be run from and elevated shell (if the script starts telling you about `ReturnValue = 2`, you're probably running it un-elevated). Some usage examples are:

- all services running as the currently logged in user, on the local host:

  `.\set-servicecredentials.ps1 -password p@ssw0rd`
- all services running as user: `somedomain\someuser` on host `somehost.somedomain`:

  `.\set-servicecredentials.ps1 somehost.somedomain somedomain\someuser p@ssw0rd`

*Set-ServiceCredentials.ps1:*

```powershell
param (
  [alias('computer', 'c')]
  [string] $computerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,

  [alias('username', 'u')]
  [string] $serviceUsername = "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME",

  [alias('password', 'p')]
  [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
  [string] $servicePassword
)
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -Script {
  param(
    [string] $computerName,
    [string] $serviceUsername,
    [string] $servicePassword
  )
  Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computerName -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class Win32_Service | Where-Object { $_.StartName -eq $serviceUsername } | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host ("Setting credentials for service: {0} (username: {1}), on host: {2}." -f $_.Name, $serviceUsername, $computerName)
    $change = $_.Change($null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $serviceUsername, $servicePassword).ReturnValue
    if ($change -eq 0) {
      Write-Host ("Service Change() request accepted.")
      if ($_.Started) {
        $serviceName = $_.Name
        Write-Host ("Restarting service: {0}, on host: {1}, to implement credential change." -f $serviceName, $computerName)
        $stop = ($_.StopService()).ReturnValue
        if ($stop -eq 0) {
          Write-Host -NoNewline ("StopService() request accepted. Awaiting 'stopped' status.")
          while ((Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computerName -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='$serviceName'").Started) {
            Start-Sleep -s 2
            Write-Host -NoNewline "."
          }
          Write-Host "."
          $start = $_.StartService().ReturnValue
          if ($start -eq 0) {
            Write-Host ("StartService() request accepted.")
          } else {
            Write-Host ("Failed to start service. ReturnValue was '{0}'. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393660(v=vs.85).aspx" -f $start) -ForegroundColor "red"
          }
        } else {
          Write-Host ("Failed to stop service. ReturnValue was '{0}'. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393673(v=vs.85).aspx" -f $stop) -ForegroundColor "red"
        }
      }
    } else {
      Write-Host ("Failed to change service credentials. ReturnValue was '{0}'. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384901(v=vs.85).aspx" -f $change) -ForegroundColor "red"
    }
  }
} -Credential "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME" -ArgumentList $computerName, $serviceUsername, $servicePassword
```

Comment: @Kiquenet I've modified the script for you to prompt for credentials to the remote host.

Answer (score 5):

Just making @alastairs's comment more visible: the 6th parameter must be `$false` instead of `$null` when you use domain accounts:

```
$service = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_Service -filter "name='serviceName'"
$service.change($null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $false, "DOMAIN\account", "mypassword")
```

Without that it was working for 4/5 of the services I tried to change, but some refused to be changed (error 21).

Comment: filter command should be -filter "name='serviceName'"

Answer (score 3):

Considering that whithin this class:

```
$class=[WMICLASS]'\\.\root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement:SqlService'
```

there's a method named **`setserviceaccount()`**, may be this [script](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/81415-change-service-account-passwords.html#post404589) will do what you want:

```
# Copyright Buck Woody, 2007
# All scripts provided AS-IS. No functionality is guaranteed in any way.
# Change Service Account name and password using PowerShell and WMI
$class = Get-WmiObject -computername "SQLVM03-QF59YPW" -namespace
root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement -class SqlService

#This remmed out part shows the services - I'll just go after number 6 (SQL
#Server Agent in my case):
# foreach ($classname in $class) {write-host $classname.DisplayName}
# $class[6].DisplayName
stop-service -displayName $class[6].DisplayName

# Note: I recommend you make these parameters, so that you don't store
# passwords. At your own risk here!
$class[6].SetServiceAccount("account", "password")
start-service -displayName $class[6].DisplayName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$svc = Get-WmiObject win32_service -filter "name='serviceName'"
```

the position of username and password can change so try this line to find the right place`$svc.GetMethodParameters("change")`

```
$svc.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,"admin-username","admin-password")
```

Answer (score 0):

What I cannot find in the default PS stack, I find it implemented in `Carbon`:

http://get-carbon.org/help/Install-Service.html

http://get-carbon.org/help/Carbon_Service.html (Carbon 2.0 only)

Answer (score 0):

The given answers do the job.

Although, there is another important detail; in order to change the credentials and run the service successfully, you first have to **grant that user account permissions to 'Log on as a Service'**.

To grant that privilege to a user, use the Powershell script provided [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Grant-Log-on-as-a-service-11a50893) by just providing the username of the account and then run the other commands to update the credentials for a service as mentioned in the other answers, i.e.,

```
$svc=gwmi win32_service -filter 'Service Name'

$svc.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,'.\username','password',$null,$null,$null)
```

Comment: error gwmi : Invalid query "select * from win32_service where myservice"

Answer (score 0):

Sc config example.  First allowing modify access to a certain target folder, then using the locked down "local service" account.  I would use set-service -credential, if I had PS 6 or above everywhere.

```
icacls c:\users\myuser\appdata\roaming\fahclient /grant "local service:(OI)(CI)(M)"
sc config "FAHClient" obj="NT AUTHORITY\LocalService"
```