# Connection to SQL Server using Windows Authentication from an application started as service

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, servicemanager

MSSQL server is running with Windows and SQL Server Authentication mode on a server called 'HOST1'.  The application which needs to connect with the SQL Server is started as a service on a server called 'HOST2'. Since the service manager starts applications as the user "NT Authority\System", I'm unable to connect with the SQL Server on 'HOST1' from 'HOST2'.

I have the option of manually changing the user account using which the services are launched. That is,

```
Right click service -> properties -> Log On -> Choose 'This Account' -> Provide a user which has permission to connect with SQL Server in 'HOST1'
```

But the problem is, there will be hundreds of services, running in hundreds of hosts. Hence modifying the user manually for all services is not possible in my case.

Please let me know how I can connect to SQL Server.

Comment: Maybe this article/class about impersonation can help you. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would using Powershell to script out a solution that is not quite as taxing? Maybe as part of the deploy process?

[Powershell script to change service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313622/powershell-script-to-change-service-account)