# Changing multiple services - Updating the Service Account - PowerShell

Tags: logging, service

Just started a new job and have been tasked with the following:

On multiple services within Services.msc

Change the 'Log on' Credentials

Currently we have a script that can do this, but its only for one service at a time

I am going to attach some articles which seem relevant, but I am really not sure. I have never written a script before

Please let me know your thoughts if this is the right track, I appreciate it!
[Powershell script to change service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313622/powershell-script-to-change-service-account)
https://www.dvlprlife.com/2022/06/set-a-windows-service-log-on-account-and-password-with-powershell/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession?view=powershell-7.2
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-service?view=powershell-7.3

A script which can change the Service Log On User for multiple Services.msc

Comment: any thoughts? bump