# Lower running program to administrator

Tags: java, service, permissions, command-line-interface

I launch an application with a cli in Java.
My Java application run in Tomcat as a service. (with system user)

When I launch my application with a cli, it is launch with system user too but I want to launch it with administrator account, not system, to avoid a problem ...
How can I do that in Java ?

Thanks !

Comment: You modify the Windows Service settings in Windows.

Comment: It's a good idea ! I will test now :)

Comment: It works ! Big thanks to you ! I was block by this problem all yesterday ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, I need to change the owner of the service to launch it with an administrator account.

You can set this with this command (https://stackoverflow.com/a/308319/2515673) :

```
sc config "service name" obj= "[.\username]" password= "[password]"
```